# Vuetify v-rating events ~ click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetifys v-rating component. I am displaying the current average rating using v-model. When a user clicks the rating component I want to update the current rating. This works good, the problem is that there will be no event emitted, when the current rating is equal to the rating the user want to give. This follows the docks, as the rating component does only emit an event when the input is changed. Any ideas how to emit an event when a star is clicked regardless if it is the same as the current one?

```
<v-rating
            :readonly="isGuest"
            color="yellow accent-4"
            background-color="grey lighten-2"
            v-model="averageRating"
            hover
            size="20"
            dense
            @input="handleRating" 
          ></v-rating>
```

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `item` slot for handling rating change:

```html
<v-rating v-model="rating">
   <template v-slot:item="props">
    <v-icon
      :color="props.isFilled ? 'blue' : 'grey lighten-1'"
      @click="handleRatingChange(props)"
    >mdi-star
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-rating>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  rating: 3
}),
methods: {
  handleRatingChange(props) {
    console.log(props.index + 1)
    this.rating = props.index + 1
  }
}
```